# Google Timeline Visualization, bars disappear if start time is not in selected range

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, timeline

The bars in my google timeline are disappearing when the start dates of my data are outside the range selected by my ChartRangeSlider. In other words, if I slide one of the sliders on the range slider, a bar on the edge of the active range will either show entirely or not at all.

I need partial bars to be visible for this to work. This is how I've configured the timeline and the slider in a dashboard...

```
// Configure range slider
        var timelineRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
            'containerId': 'timeline-filter',
            'state': 
            {
                'range': 
                {
                    'start': currentTime,
                    'end':   fourWeek                   
                }
            },
            'options': 
            {
                'filterColumnIndex': 4,
                'ui': 
                {
                    'chartType': 'ScatterChart',
                    'chartOptions': 
                    {
                        'width': '100%',
                        'height': '50',
                        'chartArea': 
                        {
                            'width': '80%', // make sure this is the same for the chart and control so the axes align right
                            'height': '80%'
                        },
                        'hAxis': 
                        {
                            'baselineColor': 'none'
                        }
                    },
                    'chartView': 
                    {
                        'columns': [4,6]
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // Configure timeline
        var timeline = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            'chartType': 'Timeline',
            'containerId': 'timeline-chart',
            'options': 
            {
                'timeline': 
                {
                    'showBarLabels': false
                },
                'width': '100%',
                'height': '325',
                'tooltip': 
                {
                    'isHtml': true
                },
                'chartArea': 
                {
                    'width': '80%', // make sure this is the same for the chart and control so the axes align right
                    'height': '80%'
                }, 
            },
            'view': 
            {
                'columns': [0,1,2,3,4,5]
            }           
        });
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. This is REALLY important for my work.

Thank you!

Comment: basically the [same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49369016/5090771) as the other, add a row for the replacement, just don't make it blank -- and use either the filter's start / end date, along with the original row's start / end date...

Comment: @WhiteHat these are definitely similar problems but they aren't exactly the same. If you adapted your previous code snippet to this question, I'll mark it as the answer. I think people may search these items individually. Thank you!