# ChartRangeFilter as a zoom function for a google timeline charts that reads data from a dedicated google spreadsheet with dataview

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts

My goal is to integrate [this zoom capability provided by Whitehat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49306638/google-timeline-visualization-dont-change-series-row-height-on-slider-interacti) into my personal timeline project:
[JsFiddle 1 - my working timeline](https://jsfiddle.net/John_Galassi/8ba6sh4d/7/)

As you can see from the jsfiddle above the code actually works and provides a working timeline:

```js
      // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
google.charts.load("current", {packages:["timeline"]});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawGID);

function drawGID() {

var query = new google.visualization.Query(
'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gDsiNSKfPdoutSbtzyt8fExliJpzIWQocEArpAQYD_g/gviz/tq?gid=0&sheet=table');
query.setQuery('select A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J LIMIT 10');
query.send(handleQueryResponse);
} //fine funzione drawGID

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
if (response.isError()) {
alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
return;
} 

// Set chart options
var options = {'width':'100%', 'height':'100%'};// fine options

var data = response.getDataTable();

//da qui proviamo dataview
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
     view.setColumns([
      { sourceColumn: 1,        id: 'materia'},
      { sourceColumn: 2,        id: 'evento'},
      { sourceColumn: 5,        id: 'start'},
      { sourceColumn: 6,        id: 'end'} /*,
      { sourceColumn: 7,        id: 'null'},
      { sourceColumn: 8,        id: 'scatter'},
      { sourceColumn: 9,        id: 'data'}*/
      ]);

var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
chart.draw(view, options);
} //fine funzione handleQueryResponse
```

The problems start when I try to ***combine*** the Whitehat's solution ***with mine***:

here I provide a jsfiddle with a working copy of Whitehat's code in the first place as a reference:
[JsFiddle 2 - Whitehat's  code ok](https://jsfiddle.net/John_Galassi/Lthkjfdc/6/)

then a jsfiddle with my attempt to mix the two codes (**not working**)
[JsFiddle 3 - Whitehat's  code mixed to mine (not working)](https://jsfiddle.net/John_Galassi/92ngqde5/43/)

and in the end a sort of *test jsfiddle*, where I output data *in the form of a data table instead of timeline*, to double check that the code was (at least partially) right
[JsFiddle 4 - output as data table instead of timeline](https://jsfiddle.net/John_Galassi/zqw1yu7r/18/)

And here is the original data base google sheet file
[timeline - google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SaDl8yACA0736r7293xXlbwzl224inJxiqaDfo_a1ZA/edit#gid=0)

My question of course is: why **jsfiddle 3** is not working? thanks

Comment: have you checked the browser's console (press F12) for errors? there are a couple syntax errors in the above code. need to remove --> `);` from the last line, and add it to the line just under --> `query.send` -- `});` -- next, the query is reporting as invalid, due to --> `offset -3`

Comment: there were three mistakes actually: first two those you mentioned, followed by an incorrect identification of column indexes within the dataview column array. And it isnt still working: now I get an "Invalid data table format: must have 3 or 4 data columns.×" error.
The problem is that I don't fully understand every passage in the code. I'll have to dwell on it

Comment: hei @WhiteHat , I just edited my question adding working jsfiddles and clear references; and a accessible copy of the original google sheet DB. It should be a lot cleaner to read now: why don't you give it a look? Thanks

Comment: hey @John -- I think it doesn't like the tooltip column because the `role` property hasn't been set on the third column. if you change the view on the chart wrapper, the chart will draw -->  `view: {columns: [0,1,3,4]}`

Comment: @WhiteHat - I've tried out your suggestion but still produces the same error anytime the wrapper is moved: ```m[(gvjs_We(...) % m.length)] is undefined```. Strangely enough, if the ```google.visualization.Query``` is limited to the first 3 records of the spreadsheet, no error occurs. You can check out the updated fiddle here if you wish: https://jsfiddle.net/John_Galassi/92ngqde5/108/ thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library like [svg-pan-zoom by Andrea Leofreddi](https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom) to add this capability to your page.

After adding the appropriate resource to your page, you can then add a function to initialize this library with your svg graph.

```
//...
chart.draw(view, options);
//Initialize the code for svgPanZoom
//Limit Paning so chart doesn't go out of viewport:
  var beforePan = function(oldPan, newPan) {
    var stopHorizontal = false;
    var stopVertical = false;
    var gutterWidth = 100;
    var gutterHeight = 100;
    // Computed variables
    var sizes = this.getSizes();
    var leftLimit = -((sizes.viewBox.x + sizes.viewBox.width) * sizes.realZoom) + gutterWidth;
    var rightLimit = sizes.width - gutterWidth - (sizes.viewBox.x * sizes.realZoom)
    var topLimit = -((sizes.viewBox.y + sizes.viewBox.height) * sizes.realZoom) + gutterHeight;
    var bottomLimit = sizes.height - gutterHeight - (sizes.viewBox.y * sizes.realZoom);

    var customPan = {};
    customPan.x = Math.max(leftLimit, Math.min(rightLimit, newPan.x));
    customPan.y = Math.max(topLimit, Math.min(bottomLimit, newPan.y));
    return customPan
  }

  var chartSvg = document.querySelector("#timeline > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > svg");
  var panZoomSvg = svgPanZoom(chartSvg, {
    fit: true,
    contain: false,
    center: true,
    beforePan: beforePan
  });

  //Resized the chart when the window is resized.
  window.onresize = function() {
    panZoomSvg.resize();
    panZoom.fit();
    panZoom.center();
  };
```

Comment: many thanks for the answer man! but I am not sure this is the solution and let me tell you why. If you zoom out to the max, you'll notice a huge amount of small pieces that are not actually readable: I need to find a way to associate some particular historical events with each level of zoom, so that for each level some elements will always stand out from the others as more important. eg: if you zoom out to the max, you'll always want to be able to identify french revolution or wwi: I need a zoom feature where this is still possible and I am not sure I am able to do that on an external library.

Comment: You can limit how much zooming out is allowed.
As far as limiting/highlighting events based on the zoom level, you could add a hook to the zooming event that toggles size, color and/or visibility.

Comment: yes, that should be my need I guess. I'll look it out thanks

Comment: I am evaluating your solution. Could you be able to provide a working fiddle as an example with both html, css and jscript parts compiled. I've read your code but it feels like something is missing. Something that may be you give for granted that I can take care of while I probably can't! thanks

Comment: @JohnGalassi Sorry man, after all this time I do not have what I used to write this answer anymore. I suggest you create a new question with the specific issues you are running into and point to this one, so someone can take a fresh look into it.